# Do I need upgraded rings for the achievement?

Tags: dark-souls-3

There is an achievement which can be completed by collecting all rings.

Does this mean that I also need to collect the upgraded versions (+1, +2) of the rings which can only be found in NG+?

Or is it enough to collect the basic versions of the rings?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you need all the rings versions to get this achievement.

That means, you can't get it until NG++.

From [Achievements](http://darksouls3.wikidot.com/achievements):

> **Master of Rings**    Acquire all 107 rings. (NG++ Required)

Answer (score 4):

Yes you have to collect every ring including their upgraded counterparts as stated on the Dark Souls 3 [rings wiki page](http://darksouls3.wiki.fextralife.com/Rings):

> To obtain the Trophy/Achievement for collecting every ring, you must collect all of the different +X variations available, making a total of 107 rings.